# Django Inlineformset with two same foreignkeys

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

Below are my needed codes for doing an inlineformset django. The problem is that I have two attributes with the same ForeignKeys and it returns a Django error

**models.py**

```
class Reference(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="user_mariner", default=None)
    verified_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, related_name="verified_by", default=None)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, default=None)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    person_contacted = models.ForeignKey(PersonReference, default=None)
    veracity_seagoing_history = models.NullBooleanField()
    health_problem = models.NullBooleanField()
    financial_liability = models.NullBooleanField()
    rehiring_prospects = models.NullBooleanField()
    character = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ReferenceForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Reference
        exclude = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
try:
    reference = Reference.objects.filter(user=id)
    ReferenceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UserProfile, Reference, fields='__all__', extra=3, can_delete=True )
    reference_form = ReferenceFormSet(request.POST or None, instance=user_profile)
except:
        print "%s - %s" % (sys.exc_info()[0], sys.exc_info()[1])

template = "application-profile/profile.html"
context_dict = {}
context_dict['reference_form'] = reference_form
return render(request, template, context_dict)
```

**profile.html**

```
{{ reference_form }}
```

**Error**

```
<type 'exceptions.ValueError'> - 'mariners_profile.Reference' has more than one ForeignKey to 'login.UserProfile'.
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `fk_name` in your inlineformset_factory call? : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#more-than-one-foreign-key-to-the-same-model

Comment: This actually answered my question. Thankyou so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the name of the field you want to use as the 'link' to the parent. Something like:

```
ReferenceFormSet = inlineformset_factory(UserProfile, Reference, fk_name='user', fields='__all__', extra=3, can_delete=True )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I am looking for!